# Код зависает на функции JS

Tags: javascript

Мой парсер падает на этой функции, ошибок не выводится, соответственно, он просто "думает" и не выводит ничего в консоль.

```
function parse() {
  var forParsing = [];
  for (var i=1; i++; i=count) {
    forParsing.push({
      tag: $('#tag'+i).val(),
      variableName: $('#variableName'+i).val(),
      variableNameFor: $('#variableNameFor'+i).val(),
    });
  }
  console.log(forParsing);
}
```

Может, какая синтаксическая ошибка, которую я явно не могу увидеть?

Comment: @Утка, там еще интереснее :-)

Comment: @Grundy у меня тоже глаз под вечер замылен))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто: неверно определение цикла.

в блоке [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) есть три части разделенные `;`

1. инициализация переменных
2. условие остановки
3. финальное выражение

В данном коде в части *условие остановки* идет постфиксный инкремент.

Цикл останавливается когда условие ложно: в данном случае когда `i` будет равно 0. И это будет весьма не скоро.

В финальном выражении идет присвоение переменной i значения `count` таким образом - сбрасывая значение установленное в части *условие остановки*.

В итоге цикл получается бесконечным, если только count не имеет значение `0`.

---

Судя по всему цикл должен был выглять так:

```
for (var i=1; i<=count;i++) {
```

То есть, повторять тело цикла, count раз.

Comment: Ух... Спасибо большое, как обычно.